# Ubuntu 23.04 Firefox And Vivaldi Browsers Are Not Working

Tags: firefox, browser, 23.04, vivaldi

How do I get firefox and vivaldi working again?
Both browsers are just a bunch of colors. I made a short about 1 minute video so people can see here: [the problem in video](https://youtu.be/5fp6E5RC3LM)

I already tried removing and reinstalling the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Run a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`
2. Logout, select the password textbox at login, notice the wheel in the bottom left side, select xorg instead of Ubuntu (Wayland).
3. In additional drivers, try to use Noveau instead of other drivers such as NVIDIA.

P.S: I also experience problems with Wayland for some applications like Skype and OBS Wayland for screen capture. (though using NVIDIA 3.90 drivers for an older NVIDIA video card)